# How to find an explicit formula for an $n$-nacci series?

Tags: functions, fibonacci-numbers

I’ve been trying to find an explicit formula for the following:
$$f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)+\cdots+f(n-a)$$
$$f(1)=F(1), f(2)=F(2), \ldots, f(a)=F(a)$$
When $F(x)$ is the $x^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number

I can easily find that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}=r=\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}r^{-k}$. We can easily see that this has $a$ number of $r$’s which I call $r_1,r_2,r_3\ldots r_a$, and we know all these values.

For the case $a=2$, we can form the formula $f(n)=\frac{r_1^n-r_2^n}{r_1-r_2}$ and for $a=3$, we have $f(n)= \frac{r_1^{n+1}}{\left(r_1-r_2\right)\left(r_1-r_3\right)}+ \frac{r_2^{n+1}}{\left(r_2-r_1\right)\left(r_2-r_3\right)}+ \frac{r_3^{n+1}}{\left(r_3-r_1\right)\left(r_3-r_2\right)}$

But for any other $a$, I’m stuck, I don’t know what operations need to be done with all the $r$’s and what will be the denominator. However, I need a formula without the floor function or an approximation, I need such a formula where we can input any $n$ such that $n\in\mathbb{C}$ gives us a perfect answer. Can anyone please help?

Instead of this, if we look at another case when

$$f(2-a)=0,f(3-a)=0,\ldots,f(a-a)=0,f(1)=1$$
Then we can see that the explicit formula can be given as:
$$f(n)=\frac{r_1^{n+a-2}}{\left(r_1-r_2\right)\left(r_1-r_3\right)\cdots\left(r_1-r_a\right)}+ \frac{r_2^{n+a-2}}{\left(r_2-r_1\right)\left(r_2-r_3\right)\cdots\left(r_2-r_a\right)}+\cdots+\frac{r_a^{n+a-2}}{\left(r_a-r_1\right)\left(r_a-r_2\right)\cdots\left(r_a-r_{a-1}\right)}$$

But my situation is a bit different, so what can I do?

Mostly I want to know about the cases $a\gt 3$

Comment: The characteristic polynomial for the usual Fibonacci numbers is just a quadratic, hence easy to solve.  Even for the [Tribonacci Numbers](https://oeis.org/A000073) the closed formula is very unpleasant.  Beyond that, I think you are stuck with numerical approximations.

Comment: @lulu, even the closed formula for tribonacci numbers can be written as $\frac{r_1^{n+1}}{\left(r_1-r_2\right)\left(r_1-r_3\right)}+ \frac{r_2^{n+1}}{\left(r_2-r_1\right)\left(r_2-r_3\right)}+ \frac{r_3^{n+1}}{\left(r_3-r_1\right)\left(r_3-r_2\right)}$

Comment: Are you calling it an "explicit formula" even when all the roots are unknown?  What use would such a formula be?

Comment: FWIW, I believe (but am not sure) that the polynomials $x^n-x^{n-1}-\cdots -1$ all have [Pisot Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PisotNumber.html) as roots.  If that is correct, then we know there is one root $\alpha$ of norm $>1$ and all the others have norm $<1$, which would show that the limit of the ratio of successive terms in your series is always $\alpha$.

Comment: @lulu all the roots are known, edited, thanks

Comment: The roots of the cubic are certainly known, but they are not particularly sensible, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%3Dx%5E2%2Bx%2B1). Above degree $3$, I'd only use numerical approximations to get them.